# Verify submitted Django form in view

Tags: python, django, forms, model-view-controller, view

I have a view, which expects a POST request. The post request should contain data submitted through a Django form.

The Django form looks something like this:

```
class SubmitForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I know I have access to the submitted data with `request.POST["title"]` and  `request.POST["comment"]`. So I can theoretically check if they're set and valid manually.

But is there a way to use `.is_valid()` (Link to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid)), to validate the submitted form?

One possibility would be to create a form in the view, fill it with the submitted data and then check it for validity.

```
data = {'title': request.POST["title"],
        'comment': request.POST["comment"]}
f = SubmitForm(data)
f.is_valid()
# True/False
```

Is there a direct way to use `is_valid()` on a submitted Django form?

Comment: That is the way to do it. `if f.is_valid():` then your logic.

Comment: You should also use the `cleaned_data` from the form.

Comment: FWIW all this is clearly documented : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
      // do your save work
```

Comment: I have the same comment as for @neverwalkaloner. Would this work? I mean `request.POST` contains various data, not just the submitted form.

Comment: what are you using? a form? if you have form then this will only take the fields in the form

Comment: Yes, I'm using a form. I see thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can write view as below:

```
def verify_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          # code here if form is valid
    else:
        form = SubmitForm() # returns empty form to be fill if not post request
    return render(request, 'template_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `request.POST` as Form argument directly:

```
form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    ....
```